# How to enable second dropdown list only after the first dropdown is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, select, drop-down-menu

I've dynamically created three dropdown lists using v-for. Now, I have trouble performing the following task. For example,

1) I want the **first** dropdown list to be **enabled** so that users can select an option.

2) The **second** and **third** dropdowns **cannot be selected** yet and must be disabled.

3) After the user selected an option from the **first** dropdown, the **second** dropdown will be **enabled** but the **third** dropdown will remain **disabled**

4) After the user selected an option from the **second** dropdown, the **third** dropdown will be **enabled** for the user to select an option from it

**Edit1** Still trying to solve this issue, help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit2** Still trying to solve this, is there anyone that can help me?

**Edit3** Here is a Codepen to work with https://codepen.io/Issaki/pen/RzzxvL

Below is my current code:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <!-- Dynamically create the select dropdowns using v-for -->
    <div v-for="(attribute, index) in attributes" :key="index">
      <label>{{attribute.type}}</label>

      <!-- Dynamically render the id to keep track of which dropdown was selected -->
      <select
        @change="selectedValue($event)"
        :id="'option' + index"
        v-model="selectedValues[index]"
      >
        <option value>Select option</option>
        <option v-for="(value, index) in attribute.values" :key="index">{{value}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // Do note that, the size of this array is not fixed.
      // At the moment, there is only three objects in the array
      attributes: [
        {
          type: "Color",
          values: ["Black", "White", "Yellow"]
        },
        {
          type: "Size",
          values: ["Small", "Medium", "Large"]
        },
        {
          type: "Finish",
          values: ["Shiny", "Glossy"]
        }
      ],

      selectedValues: []
    };
  },

  methods: {
    selectedValue(e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log(this.selectedValues);
      if (e.target.id === "option0") {
        if (this.selectedValues[0] === "") {
          document.getElementById("option1").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("option2").disabled = true;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("option1").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("option2").disabled = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Just passing by, not enough time to answer. The other thing you'll need to think about is what if you have 1st and 2nd dropdowns selected and someone goes back and changes the 1st dropdown. Make sure you now remove 2nd dropdowns selection and also disable the 3rd dropdown again! Cheers

Comment: @haag1 Hi, thanks for the reply! There is alot of stuff to keep track off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to resort to element ids or direct manipulation of the DOM. You can keep it all in the template just by setting the `disabled` attribute depending on how many values have been selected.

Figuring out which `select` has been changed can be done just by passing the `index` to the `@change` handler.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    attributes: [
      {
        type: "Color",
        values: ["Black", "White", "Yellow"]
      },
      {
        type: "Size",
        values: ["Small", "Medium", "Large"]
      },
      {
        type: "Finish",
        values: ["Shiny", "Glossy"]
      }
    ],

    selectedValues: []
  },

  methods: {
    selectValue (index, value) {
      const newValues = this.selectedValues.slice(0, index)

      if (value) {
        newValues.push(value)
      }

      this.selectedValues = newValues
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(attribute, index) in attributes" :key="index">
    <label>{{ attribute.type }}</label>
    <select
      @change="selectValue(index, $event.target.value)"
      :value="selectedValues[index]"
      :disabled="selectedValues.length < index"
    >
      <option :value="undefined">Select option</option>
      <option v-for="(value, index) in attribute.values" :key="index">{{ value }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>{{ selectedValues }}</div>
</div>
```